# Spago BI source in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, svn, spagobi

I'm trying to work with Spago BI 5.1 SRC in Eclipse. I work for an insurance company, and We're using a modified version of Spago BI for some specifical clients for example. The thing is that I would like to modify some more detailed things, and the only way to do it is working with the source code.

I tried to do it from the GitHub and SVN repositories, with no results.

Also downloaded the src from the web but I have no idea about how to import it in Eclipse.

Made Tomcat work, but as I said previously, do not know how should I import the source code folder of Spago BI, so localhost:8080 works, but localhost:8080/SpagoBIProject (only an example) doesn't.

The Environment:

**Windows 7 Professional x64**

**Eclipse Luna 4.4.2**

**Tomcat 7**

So, finally, how should I import and edit the source code?

Answer (score 1):

The source is available on SVN, as according to this page:
https://forge.ow2.org/plugins/scmsvn/index.php?group_id=204

> Anonymous SVN Access
>
> This project's SVN repository can be checked out through anonymous
>   svnserver with the following instruction set. The module you wish to
>   check out must be specified as the modulename (if you don't know which
>   module is defined or if no module is set, just remplace modulename by
>   .).
>
> svn checkout svn://svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/spagobi modulename

In Eclipse, you would add the SVN repository to your SVN Repositories, using the URL 
svn://svn.forge.objectweb.org/svnroot/spagobi
and then you would check out the whole trunk, or just the specific module you need. The modules already contain eclipse .project files, so they should be automatically imported as Java projects and built after checkout.

To run the modules in you local Tomcat, you will have to build them as webapps and deploy them to your local server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Finally i just edit the files with a plain text editor, and compiled with ant. (If somebody need it, i could explain it, is pretty easy)

Comment: can you please give me a step by step guide?
i have tomcat, spagobi src with all the modules, i imported as existing project.. (tomcat is working)